# Video meta/tag editor

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing, command-line

I'm looking for a free/gratis metadata/tag editor for the most common video containers, including `mkv`, `mp4`, `wmv`, `avi`, and `flv`, whenever possible. I'd prefer command line, for Windows.

I tried [`ffmpeg`](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_Metadata), but it won't support full metadata editing and it will have to remux (rebuild) the file to change the tags/metadata.

Comment: Looking at the scarcity of responses gathered from this question since 2015, I guess that broadening its scope would be great, even if the tool happens to be GUI-based (like exfalso, easytag, puddletag, musicbrainz Picard etc.).

Comment: There are many answers for this, I just don't have the time now, when I can I'll post soon. However, audiophiles forums/webpages are the places you want to look for. Another thing is: why do you believe ffmpeg isn't enough?

Answer (score 1):

MusicBrainz Picard handles mostly all video containers (with the appropriate plugin). If the videos are music videos, it'll be even easier to tag them with MusicBrains massive db.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if one of the [Unix question-related tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4961/which-mp3-tagging-tool-for-linux) is available for Windows.

Then I quickly found this [Best Metadata Editors](https://www.movavi.com/learning-portal/metadata-editor.html), see what suits you best, and comment here.

The [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) also is available in both Linux/Windows to both command/GUI interfaces.